# How to work with specific range of numbers in lists in scheme?

Tags: list, scheme, lisp, racket

I'm learning scheme and I would like to know how to remove, for example the negative numbers of a list so I can work with the positives, until now I only got  # instead of removing the negatives.
Here is my code:

```
 (define test
    (lambda (list)
      (map (lambda (x) (if (> x 0) x ))list)))
```

Comment: You can use [filter](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=filter#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29).

Comment: @Renzo I know, but I am using a previous version of it, because my college won't adapt. So I am trying in this way.

Comment: I am using version 372 of scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned the negatives of the list into 0 so it doesn't affect what I do.

Here's the code for it:

```
 (define test
   (lambda(list)
        (map (lambda (x)(if (> x  0) x
                    0 ))list)  ) )
```

Comment: good idea, if you're searching for a maximum. with minimum, not so good. :) but, you can go a bit further with this: turn each positive `x` into `(list x)`, and each negative `x` turn into `(list )` (without the `x`, i.e. the empty list). Next, `(apply append ...)` to the resulting list of lists (where some are singleton lists, and others are empty). What will be the result? (for example, try `(apply append (list '(1) '() '(3)))`).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the standard version of `filter`:

```
(define (filter pred? xs)
  (let loop ((xs xs) (ys '()))
    (cond ((null? xs) (reverse ys))
          ((pred? (car xs))
            (loop (cdr xs) (cons (car xs) ys)))
          (else (loop (cdr xs) ys)))))
```

With that, you can build a new list containing only the positive values of the input list:

```
> (filter positive? '(3 9 -2 4 0 -1 7))
(3 9 4 7)
```

You might enjoy [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com), which provides lots of Scheme code for you to study.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to disect and rebuild the list element by element. This is a very common recursive pattern in Scheme and should be covered in depth in your course material.

```
(define (filter list pred)
  (cond ((null? list)
          '())
        ((pred (car list))
          (filter (cdr list) pred))
        (else
          (cons (car list) (filter (cdr list) pred)))))
```

Comment: You can make your version more in line with the built-in `filter` by consing all elements whose predicate value is true (instead of the opposite).

Comment: code is nice and clean but -
list is a [scheme keyword](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-keywords) - it should never be used as an argument's name